# WPF DataGrid: Making an entire column unselectable

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which holds a few columns, some of them shouldn't be selectable to the user (since they're read-only anyway).
There is no property for the column itself, apparently I need to handle this through the SelectedCellsChanged-Event.

I can use an IF-statement to find out whether the corresponding column of a cell is non-selectable by doing something like this:

```
private void chartDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedCells[0].Column.Header.ToString() == "Non Selectable Column")
        {
            // What now?
        }
}
```

How do I keep the cells in this collection from getting selected, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I got it. It may not be the perfect solution, but it works flawlessly for me. Even with lots of cells AND when selecting cells from several columns containin ones that should be selectable. :)

```
private void chartDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in e.AddedCells)
    {
        if (cell.Column.Header.ToString() == "NonSelectableColumn")
        {
            MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.Remove(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should mark this as answer if you don't expect any more responses (it looks reasonable enough).